# json value error while recieving long integer value

Tags: php, json

I am sending array JSON request to the server with big integer array and when I receive them and decode the JSON it convert the integer values to  scientific notation format i am using php funtions.

```
{
    "friend_ids": [2719267598135496,2719267598135497]
}

(
    [friend_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2.7192675981355E+15
            [1] => 2.7192675981355E+15
        )

)
```

This is the JSON request I am receiving this value. I wnat this as same that i m sending to the server

Comment: Those are the same numbers/values. It isn't clear what your question is.

Comment: Are you running 32 or 64 bit PHP - check `echo PHP_INT_MAX;` to see what size integer it can cater for.

Comment: when i am sending big int value as string i will work fine but not in int format

Comment: @Dave i know they are same but what wiill be the method to get same sa sending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has issues with larger numbers at times. Luckily, json_decode has an option that will convert large numbers to strings:

```
json_decode($json, TRUE, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

will return this:

```
array(1) {
  ["friend_ids"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(16) "2719267598135496"
    [1]=>
    string(16) "2719267598135497"
  }
}
```